# Why does the Perl Debugger hang on R(eload) when debugging a module?

Tags: perl, debugging, module, freeze

In Perl 5.18.2 of SLES12 SP5 I'm suffering from the Perl debugger hanging after `R` when a module is being tested like this:

```perl-db
% perl -Ilib -mSimple -d -e1

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.39_10
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

Simple::CODE(0x215fa60)(lib/Simple.pm:19):
19:         die "bad\n"
20:             if (something);
  DB<1> n
Simple::CODE(0x1e6fde0)(lib/Simple.pm:4):
4:      require 5.018_000;
  DB<1> R
Warning: some settings and command-line options may be lost!

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.39_10
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

^C^C^C^C^Z
[2]+  Stopped                 perl -Ilib -mSimple -d -e1
```

It works for any module, but for the sake of completeness, here's the one I wrote for demonstrating:

```perl
% cat lib/Simple.pm
#!/usr/bin/perl
package Simple;

require 5.018_000;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub something
{
    use integer;
    my $result = 0;

    return $result;
}

UNITCHECK {
    $DB::single = 1;
    die "bad\n"
        if (something);
}

1;
```

### More Insights

Using `strace` I realized that Perl is actually reading lines from `STDIN` (fd 0).
Attaching `gdb` to the process when using `R`, I got this output (openSUSE Leap 15.4 this time):

```gdb
Continuing.
process 2427 is executing new program: /usr/bin/perl
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00007ff83747071e in read () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
Missing separate debuginfos, use: zypper install perl-base-debuginfo-5.26.1-150300.17.14.1.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ff83747071e in read () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x000055933f42576d in PerlIOUnix_read ()
#2  0x000055933f428ba8 in PerlIOBuf_fill ()
#3  0x000055933f4272a8 in Perl_PerlIO_fill ()
#4  0x000055933f428aa0 in PerlIOBase_read ()
#5  0x000055933f42aa78 in PerlIO_getc ()
#6  0x000055933f3c0595 in Perl_sv_gets ()
#7  0x000055933f326d37 in Perl_lex_next_chunk ()
#8  0x000055933f330bd3 in Perl_yylex ()
#9  0x000055933f34489d in Perl_yyparse ()
#10 0x000055933f318617 in perl_parse ()
#11 0x000055933f2f0e5c in main ()
```

### Another Update

As Perl seems to read from STDIN (but does *not* display the debugger prompt), I entered <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on Linux.
Then I got the output:

```perl-db
Debugged program terminated.  Use q to quit or R to restart,
use o inhibit_exit to avoid stopping after program termination,
h q, h R or h o to get additional info.
```

Now if you assume the user should simply enter Perl debugger commands when Perl is reading input, the answer is that Perl does not process any, so I was assuming the Perl Debugger hangs.

### Final mystery

So I realized that Perl debugger is reading from input, ^D does terminate the non-processing state, and commands entered between restart and ^D are not being processed.
Eventually I realized that those commands are echoed, but not processed after having entered EOF:

```perl-db
  DB<0> R
Warning: some settings and command-line options may be lost!

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.39_10
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

l
ghgh
<<<<<<<<< ^D (EOF) entered here
main::(-:1):    l
main::(-:2):    ghgh
```

Eventually I wonder whether `libreadline` might play any role there, seeing (in `strace` output):

```strace
open("/lib64/libreadline.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

Comment: Not answering your question, but worth noting that `R` preserves only command line switches  -w, -I, and -e. So your -m is lost.

Comment: Didn't know that, but `R` for `perl -Ilib -d -e1` does not show that (d)effect.

Comment: I still don't know what happens, but according to an `strace` Perl is reading lines up to 8kB from `STDIN` without echoing or obvious processing after `R`.